# Return List<T> via WCF service

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linq-to-sql

I'm writing WP 8 application where I need to return list of users via WCF service. 
I have two tables in the database: `Users` (contains location and other user's data) and `Tabs` (contains two fields `u1ID`(my Id) and `u2ID`(user I can see on the map). Thus I get all `u2ID` and compare them to `Id` field of the `Users` table. If they are similar - I add this user to the list.
But `getAllusrs` method returns only first record from the database. How can I correct it?

My service implementation:

```
public List<Point> getAllusrs() 
        {
            DataClasses1DataContext data = new DataClasses1DataContext();
            var a = (from s in data.Tabs where s.u1ID == 1 select s.u2ID).ToArray();
            int inc = 0;
                List<Point> location = new List<Point>();

                foreach (var d in data.Users)
                {
                    if (a[inc] != null && d.Id == a[inc]) 
                    {
                        location.Add(new Point() { Lat = d.usrLat, Lon = d.usrLong });
                        inc++;
                    }
                }
                return location;
        }
```

Comment: Your looping constructs do not make sense to me. Maybe you can explain in english what you want to achieve?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a WCF problem.

Comment: @nvoigt, added an explanation to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to work on your basic loops.

```
public List<Point> GetAllUsers() 
{
    var data = new DataClasses1DataContext();

    var userIds = data.Tabs.Where(t => t.u1ID == 1).Select(t => t.u2ID).ToList();

    var users = data.Users.Where(u => userIds.Contains(u.Id)).ToList();

    var locations = users.Select(u => new Point { Lat = u.usrLat, Lon = u.usrLong }).ToList();

    return locations;
}
```

You should probably do all this stuff on the database, not materializing it in between like I did.